# Microsoft Excel Default message

Tags: excel

I am performing a weighted average analysis which has 5 parameters. If any of the 5 parameter is 0, then the weight of that parameter gets distributed to the other parameters. The code is working fine, but when I am opening the excel file I am getting the following default Microsoft Excel Message.

[image]

So for each row if say A,B are not present, then I am receiving the message 2 times.I can click on the OK button and move on, but the problem is I have 4000 rows and this message is coming many times. 
Could anyone please help me. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: This looks like a messagewindow launching from the macro (not a built-in Excel warning).  Check the code and see what triggers that?  I'd tell you where in the code this is coming from, but you haven't posted any.

Comment: I agree with Batm... cof cof... BruceWayne.
I remember it is possible to disable warnings in VBA, perhaps that's what you're looking for.
Try something like:
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False`

Comment: open the project and do ctrl + F whole project and search for "CPO empty"  to see if can quickly locate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your responses. Bruce, you were absolutely correct sir. It was a line in the code that was triggering the message. Removed it and the code works fine now.